# Splitting training and test data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Can someone recommend what is the best percent of divided the training data and testing data in Machine learning. What are the disadvantages if i split training and test data in **30-70 percentage** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one "right way" to split your data unfortunately, people use different values which are chosen based on different heuristics, gut feeling and personal experience/preference. A good starting point is the [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) (**80-20**).

Sometimes using a simple split isn't an option as you might simply have too much data - in that case you might need to sample your data or use smaller testing sets if your algorithm is computationally complex. An important part is to **randomly choose** your data. The trade-off is pretty simple: **less testing data** = the performance of your algorithm will have bigger variance. **Less training data** = parameter estimates will have bigger variance.

For me personally more important than the size of the split is that you obviously shouldn't always perform your tests only once on the same test split as it might be biased (you might be lucky or unlucky with your split). That's why you should do tests for several configurations (for instance you run your tests X times each time choosing a different 20% for testing). Here you can have problems with the so called model variance - different splits will result in different values. That's why you should run tests several times and average out the results.

With the above method you might find it troublesome to test all the possible splits. A well established method of splitting data is the so called [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#Common_types_of_cross-validation) and as you can read in the wiki article there are several types of it (both exhaustive and non-exhaustive). Pay extra attention to the **k-fold cross validation**.

Comment: Note that cross validation is often used to determine hyperparameters.  In this case your folds will only be of train data.  Your test data must remain untouched until the very end where you can use it to determine effectiveness of your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the various strategies for cross-validation.

A 10%-90% split is popular, as it arises from 10x cross-validation.
But you could do 3x or 4x cross validation, too. (33-67 or 25-75)

Much larger errors arise from:

- having **duplicates** in both test and train
- unbalanced data

Make sure to first merge all duplicates, and do stratified splits if you have unbalanced data.